# Not seeing a table when I expand a database but when I query it returns results

Tags: sql, database-administration

[image]

When I run select * from tableTest I am getting 0 rows with column headers.
When I expand the database -->Tables I am not seeing this TableTest.

I have sa previleges on this server. Can you help me figure out why this is happening and how can I see tableTest under tables?

Comment: Have you tried to refresh, or re open your ssms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to check is what object type is this.

`run sp_help 'tableTest'`

Comment: Thank you. It is a view and I am looking inside tables.